# Excel formula errors when not referencing a physical array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to return the number of months of storage where the sum of all previous months is equal to the one time removal rate in one cell using the values below:

[image: Values]

I have come to the following solution of creating an array with a length of 12 of the applicable monthly rates. Which is as follows {.5,.5,.5,.6,.6,.6,.6,.6,.6,.9,.9,.9}

I then use the following function to find the running total for each number in the array:

```
LET(array,$D$9:$O$9,MAP(array,LAMBDA(x,SUM(INDEX(array,1,1):x))))
```

Then I can easily =match(removal rate, returned array,1) to find the index of the value I need, which is my answer since the index of the array corresponds to the months since the start of the array.

[image: Sheet so far with formulas]

My issue is that the following formulas work when separated but don't work when combined:

**Works:**

```
LET(monArray,SEQUENCE(1,12),IFS(monArray<=3,0.5,monArray<=9,0.6,monArray<=12,0.9))
MATCH(D4,LET(array,$D$9:$O$9,MAP(array,LAMBDA(x,SUM(INDEX(array,1,1):x)))),1)
```

**Does not work:**

```
=LET(ratearray,LET(monArray,SEQUENCE(1,12),IFS(monArray<=3,0.5,monArray<=9,0.6,monArray<=12,0.9)),MATCH(D4,LET(array,ratearray,MAP(array,LAMBDA(x,SUM(INDEX(array,1,1):x)))),1))
```

I believe I have found the issue which is that the LAMBDA function has issues when not referencing an actual array and instead referencing an alias or formula.

**Works:**

```
MATCH(6,MAP($D$9:$O$9,LAMBDA(x,SUM(INDEX($D$9:$O$9,1):x))),1)
```

**Does not work:**

```
MATCH(6,MAP(VSTACK($D$9:$O$9),LAMBDA(x,SUM(INDEX(VSTACK($D$9:$O$9),1):x))),1)
```

The use of: `VSTACK($D$9:$O$9)` breaks the lambda function.

I am open to fixes that fix the issues using my formula and provide a work around for the LAMBDA limitation or fixes that completely rewrite my formulas to provide the original result.

I am not open to VBA answers I think this can be done without and the final destination of this formula will not allow for a Macro Enabled Worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use a range reference when using `INDEX(array,1,1):x` That is going to require a Range and not an array.  The array does not have an address to convert to a range.

But there is a better formula called SCAN that will build the sum array that does not rely on using a range:

```
=MATCH(D4,SCAN(0,D9:O9,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),1)
```

Because it loops the array and does not require a range reference built we can use your array builder:

```
=MATCH(D4,SCAN(0,LET(monArray,SEQUENCE(1,12),IFS(monArray<=3,0.5,monArray<=9,0.6,TRUE,0.9)),LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),1)
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew there was information missing from my Index function but I didn't know what it was AND you rewrote the complete function thank you sir! I will implement this tomorrow.